# VideoReader/read in matlab

Tags: matlab

I use matlab 2018 in Windows 10.
I got an error message in reading avi-File in Matlab.

```
v = VideoReader('M-Movie_1.avi');
video = read(v);
```

I got this error-message

```
Error using VideoReader/read>readFramesUntilEnd (line 229)
Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

Error in VideoReader/read (line 120)
    videoFrames = readFramesUntilEnd(obj);

Error in main (line 7)
video = read(v);
```

any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: R2018a or R2018b? Are you sure that your avi file is not corrupted?

Comment: Try using readFrame(v) instead of read(v). Please check the video address too. If you provide more line of code it would be more clear.